# Duplicate nested objects in Realm database

Tags: android, realm

My application is extrapolating data from a [GFTS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/) feed with many different tables. It has many lists contained in lists to keep relationships between tables.

For some reason Realm is creating a duplicate list instance within TripUpdate - stop_time_update. 
[image]

The instance I am referring in code is nulled while realm creates a shadow copy with the values. Any ideas on what's happening?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question? The debugger doesn't show the correct values because they are lazy-loaded. See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#testing-and-debugging

Comment: How about setting primary key? If so, Realm can detect what is duplicate.